# is _id of document affects on scoring?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I add two same documents the only different thing is _id of documents (I restart scenario for each of them and I do not add them sequentially. to be sure my test is correct)

one of them changes order of result of this query and one of them does not:

```
GET index_for_test/business/_search
{

    "query": {
            "multi_match": {
            "query":       "italian",
            "type":        "most_fields",
            "fields":      [ "name^2", "categories" ]
          }
    }
}
```

my original question was:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10341

Comment: Are the query result scores the same?

Comment: it caused by search type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&hl=en-GB#!topic/elasticsearch/VWqA_P4zzH8
my answer is in this documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch
documents are spread in 5 shards by default and queries run with an algorithm that scores documents in each shard and then fetch them, in small data this ends to inaccurate result so if the database is small it is better to run you queries with search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch but it has scalability problems and should be changed when it grows